# is there any option to temporarily stop materialised view refresh for few hours in oracle

Tags: database, oracle11g, database-administration

We have many materialized views(MV) in ORacle 11G which take long time to refresh. since every MV is running at a interval of 1 hour time. We have a huge performance hit in the production environment. Instead of changing the refresh time in each MV, is there any option in Oracle 11G to temporarily pause all DB refresh.

Comment: Assuming that Oracle is refreshing the materialized views every hour (rather than you having some job that refreshes them every hour), in 11g there should be a row in `dba_jobs` for each refresh job.  You could set `job_queue_processes` to 0 which would stop those from refreshing (and stop any other jobs from running).  Or you could temporarily break just the refresh jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the materialized view so that it is refresh on demand. E.g.

```
alter materialized view view_name refresh on demand;
```

You can later restore whatever refresh options you want.

Of course, this only alters 1 view, not all materialized views in the database. You might find reviewing [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2002.htm#i2233205) is helpful. If you really meant you wanted to stop refresh of all materialized views, you probably want to write dynamic sql by creating a alter command for each entry in all_mviews or user_mviews